# Javascript Date "Invalid Date" in IE when copying very old dates

Tags: javascript, date

Code:

```
var x = new Date(Date.UTC(0, 0, 0));
x.setUTCFullYear(0);

// in Firefox, writes "Date {Sat Dec 30 0000 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)}"
// in IE, writes "LOG: Sat Dec 30 16:00:00 PST 1 B.C."
console.log(x);  

// Create a copy of x
var y = new Date(x);

// in Firefox, writes "Date {Sat Dec 30 0000 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)}"
// in IE, writes "LOG: Invalid Date"

console.log(y);
```

This seems to happen for any very old dates

**My question(s)**: What exactly is invalid here, and why only IE? How can I move past this problem and actually create a copy of the date?

Comment: What about `var y = new Date(x.getTime());`?

Comment: What version of IE, and does it happen only in compatibility mode or always?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)

Comment: @Ejay—and your point is?

Comment: IE might be doing it right `there is a year zero in astronomical year numbering (where it coincides with the Julian year 1 BC)`. No super point, just a comment, as you can notice :)

Comment: It's always best to start with [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9). Javascript date objects are defined as using the Gregorian system, extended forwards and backwards from when it was introduced. The astronomical system is not applicable here.

Comment: @Pointy - that does work as intended for helping move past the issue - still not clear _why_ it happens though

Comment: @UtopiaLtd - IE9. My original settings are: Browser Mode: IE9 Compat View, Document Mode: Quirks. Seems to happen for all Document Modes and Browser Modes though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that when a date object is passed to the Date constructor in IE, it's evaluated as something other than the time value (probably calls `toString`).

To force it to evaluate to the time value, you can do:

```
new Date(x.getTime());
```

or

```
new Date(+x);
```

or any expression that makes the date return its time value rather than a string.

When a single value is passed to the [Date constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), it's converted to a primitive. The specification doesn't say whether it should be converted to a string or number. So IE isn't non–compliant, it's just behaving differently.

It is unusual though that IE doesn't seem to correctly parse it's own string representation of a date in this case. It seems to fail for any date before 70-01-01, which may be moot since the Gregorian calendar was only introduced in 1582. The time value itself can cover dates from 283458 BC to 287396 AD.

Anyway, the fix is simple.

#### Edit 2016

In [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), passing a Date to the Date constructor called *Date.prototype.toString* so the constructor then had to parse it's own string version of the date. [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value) fixed that so the time value is used directly instead.

However, not all browsers support ECMAScript 2015 yet so even though the chance of `new Date(date)` returning an incorrect value are small and becoming smaller by the day, it's still safer to use `+date` (until IE 8 is completely gone).

Comment: Well put RobG. Thanks for the insight!